# “GPG Error: Clearsigned file isn't valid” When Installing Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, web, database

I am trying to install mongodb using the instructions provided on this page.

http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/introduction-to-the-mean-stack-part-one-setting-up-your-tools/

I get to the step where you do "sudo apt-get update" and most of this runs just fine until I get the error as follows.

E: GPG error: http://downlaods-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

This means I can't continue with the installation. Is there any way I can fix this? I am completely lost.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try using these instructions instead. The ones you are using are outdated: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Using those instructions, I get the same exact error.

Comment: Take a look at the following which reports a fix for a similar error. It may address: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=158651

Comment: Same error after attempting the solution which worked. Is it something with my connection or the server the files are hosted on?

Comment: From what I have read this is likely an error with your local package manager. Not my area of expertise unfortunately. Maybe someone else can assist on this. You may want to try posting on serverfault in any case rather than stackoverflow as this is a system administration issue rather than a development one. Good luck!